# Randomly Selecting Polygons within Buffer

Tags: qgis

I am trying to select random polygons in a shapefile.  I have successfully used the research tool Random Selection to do so. 
The next step is to randomly select polygons within buffered regions of the same shapefile.

I tried merging the "buffer layer" to my county layer and performing a Random Selection within Subsets, selecting the newly added buffer column as the Inset Subset Field.  This jams my computer even though I only asked it to select a few counties.

Any thoughts? Other ways to do this?

Comment: To help you please tell me of I understand the problem. You want to select random features of a shapefile within various buffer. Are there multiple buffer in the shape file? Should only be features of a certain buffer be selected or random features of all buffers?

Comment: There are multiple buffers in shp. And there is only a single feature within the shp that should be selected..

Comment: I figured out a way. I simply clipped my original shape file by the buffer and then performed a Random Selection.